# Grid interpolation using a new calculated field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, interpolation

Still learning....
I am trying to run the grid interpolation tool on a point shp file.  I can successfully use the tool with the existing data but cannot run the tool on a new field I created in the field calculator.  When I select the Z field all the original data is present except the new field that I created.  I have saved all my edits and even resaved the shp file as something different with the same results.  When I am in edit mode I can create a new field and populate the field manually and that I can interpolate but if that new field was created in the field calculator it does not work.  Just wondering if I am missing a step or two.

I am using the latest version of QGIS Essens

Comment: Perhaps the new field you have created is a text one? How do you run the field calculator?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  

My first thought as well was that the new field was a string but I tried it several times using Whole Number and Decimal Number.  In the layers properties it also lists it as a "Real" number.  

The data I have contains soil test data. I attempt to create a new field in the calculator by using as an example

case
when "pH" <= 6 then 3000
when "pH" <= 6.5 then 2000
else 0
end

The process works, the new field is populated, I save my edits yet the new field will not show up in the drop down in the grid interpolation tool.

Thanks again